# What is the best way of getting accuracy when epochs in model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

am using folding number = 10 and epoch=30.

in each fold, the training will be repeated 30 times and the weights will be affected by this.

the accuracy of the first epoch is much lower than the accuracy at the end and this is normal because the weights are getting better.

so how could I represent the accuracy of this fold?
*if I did the mean of accuracies (of each epoch)  it will be negatively affected by the accuracy of first epochs.*

**is it a good idea to make predict() on test data and get the final accuracy of each fold from it after finishing the 30 epochs?**

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to report the mean of the accuracies of all epochs? In general, we output the accuracy of the model on the test data after training has finished. So normally we do not measure the test accuracy after each epoch, because that would compromise the results.

However, if you want to improve the accuracy on the test data, you can split the training data into training and validation and then use the early stop approach based on the validation accuracy, or you can do all the 30 epochs and then test on the model that yielded the best validation accuracy, something like this:

```
best_accu = 0
num_epochs = 30
for epochs in range(num_epochs):
    h = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split=0.1, verbose=0, epochs=1)
    if h.history['val_accuracy'][-1]>best_accu:
        best_accu = h.history['val_accuracy'][-1]
        model.save.weights('temp.h5')
    print('Epoch %d/%d'%(epochs+1, num_epochs)
    print('loss: %.04f - acc: %.04f - val_loss: %.04f - val_acc: %.04f'%(h.history['loss'][-1], h.history['accuracy'][-1], h.history['val_loss'][-1], h.history['val_accuracy'][-1]))

model.load_weights('temp.h5')
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```